# How to mask a TextField to show the dd/mm/yyyy date format in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-compose-textfield

Using Jetpack Compose, how can I format the TextField value to follow the "dd/mm/yyyy" format?

Answer (score 12):

### Updated Answer

Implementation of VisualTranformation that accepts any type of mask for Jetpack Compose TextField:

```
class MaskVisualTransformation(private val mask: String) : VisualTransformation {

    private val specialSymbolsIndices = mask.indices.filter { mask[it] != '#' }

    override fun filter(text: AnnotatedString): TransformedText {
        var out = ""
        var maskIndex = 0
        text.forEach { char ->
            while (specialSymbolsIndices.contains(maskIndex)) {
                out += mask[maskIndex]
                maskIndex++
            }
            out += char
            maskIndex++
        }
        return TransformedText(AnnotatedString(out), offsetTranslator())
    }

    private fun offsetTranslator() = object : OffsetMapping {
        override fun originalToTransformed(offset: Int): Int {
            val offsetValue = offset.absoluteValue
            if (offsetValue == 0) return 0
            var numberOfHashtags = 0
            val masked = mask.takeWhile {
                if (it == '#') numberOfHashtags++
                numberOfHashtags < offsetValue
            }
            return masked.length + 1
        }

        override fun transformedToOriginal(offset: Int): Int {
            return mask.take(offset.absoluteValue).count { it == '#' }
        }
    }
}
```

How to use it:

```
@Composable
fun DateTextField() {
    var date by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    TextField(
        value = date,
        onValueChange = {
            if (it.length <= DATE_LENGTH) {
                date = it
            }
        },
        visualTransformation = MaskVisualTransformation(DATE_MASK)
    )
}

object DateDefaults {
    const val DATE_MASK = "##/##/####"
    const val DATE_LENGTH = 8 // Equals to "##/##/####".count { it == '#' }
}
```

### Old Answer

Just as Jetpack Compose offers the Visual Transformation of the password, we can do our own visual transformation.

```
class DateTransformation : VisualTransformation {

    // XX/XX/XXXX format
    override fun filter(text: AnnotatedString): TransformedText {
        var out = ""
        text.text.forEachIndexed { index, char ->
            when (index) {
                2 -> out += "/$char"
                4 -> out += "/$char"
                else -> out += char
            }
        }
        val numberOffsetTranslator = object : OffsetMapping {
            override fun originalToTransformed(offset: Int): Int {
                if (offset <= 2) return offset
                if (offset <= 4) return offset + 1
                return offset + 2
            }

            override fun transformedToOriginal(offset: Int): Int {
                if (offset <= 2) return offset
                if (offset <= 5) return offset - 1
                return offset - 2
            }
        }
        return TransformedText(AnnotatedString(out), numberOffsetTranslator)
    }
}
```

We return a TransformedText with the filter applied and an OffsetMapping that translates between the original and transformed text.

Now, we can use our Visual Transformation class in any TextField.

```
var text by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
TextField(
    value = text,
    visualTransformation = DateTransformation(),
    keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number),
    onValueChange = {
        if (it.length < 9) text = it
    }
)
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your solution. I just have a doubt. My state has a different text structure comparing to what it is on the field. On the field is "01/01/2000" and, in my state, the value is: "01012000". How can I solve this?

Comment: In fact, the visual transformation only changes the visual. You have to change the value elsewhere, like in the viewmodel or usecase. You can use part of the code above to do this. Example: https://gist.github.com/the-thiago/4c3d421310501a4a7f3bef2bb94a6ef6

Comment: Nice, thanks! I'd just change "out" to a StringBuilder to avoid multiple reallocations.